# Upload multiple files takes long time in ftp

Tags: php, ftp

I want to **upload multiple files** using ftp in php. Just want to make sure that I am doing it correctly or the good way. I am able to upload the file on my localhost but after I transfer the project to the server, It takes time to upload.

Sometimes, it also give an error `unable to connect to ftp` if I upload more than 1 files. Below are the codes that I did.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['uploaded']['name']); $i++){
    $array = array($_FILES['uploaded']['name']);
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $filesize = $_FILES['uploaded']['size'][$i];

    if($filesize > 10485760){
      $msgError[] = "Exceed maximum file size!";    
    }   

    if($tmpFilePath != ""){
      $shortname = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i];

      $filePath = $date.'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i];

      // Start FTP Connection 
      require "../ftp-conn.php";

      $file = $tmpFilePath;

      $remote_file = "/public_html/procurement/uploads/" . $filePath;

      // turn passive mode on
      ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

      // upload a file
      if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
      } else {
        die ("There was a problem while uploading $file\n");
      }

      // close the connection
        ftp_close($conn_id);
      }

}
```

Is there a better solution for this?

> Update codes:

```
// Start FTP Connection 
$ftp_server = "ftp.myweb.com";
$ftp_user_name = 'user';
$ftp_user_pass = 'password';

// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or

die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

//Function to check file size and upload file if success
for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['uploaded']['name']); $i++){
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $filesize = $_FILES['uploaded']['size'][$i];

    if($filesize > 10485760){
        $msgError[] = "Exceed maximum file size!";
    }

    if($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $shortname = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i];
        $filePath = $date.'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i];

        $file = $tmpFilePath;
        $remote_file = "/public_html/procurement/uploads/" . $filePath;

        if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY)) {
            echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
        } else {
            die ("There was a problem while uploading $file\n");
        }

    }

}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Comment: Why do you open and close the connection in every iteration?

Comment: @noahnu in that case the open and close connection should be outside of the loop?

Comment: Yes, including the `ftp_pasv`. Opening the connection probably takes some time.

Comment: thanks @noahnu. Will try it

Comment: @noahnu I already edit the code like you suggest but still if I upload more than 1 files, it give me the error `unable to connect to ftp`. Do I need to make any network setting on the server or on my ftp connection?

Comment: Show us your new code. And expand the `ftp-conn.php` include file. We need to see a complete code.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I updated the code. If I update more than 1 files or if it takes time to load, it will fail. I also change the `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` on .htaccess but still with the same result.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl before the ftp connection I have a form validation. Does it effect the ftp connection or if I replace the ftp connection at the beginning of the script, will it make any different?

Comment: "it will fail" - How does it fail? What does it do? + Regarding the form: I do not think it makes difference. But it's your job to try! You should have started yourself by testing a simple FTP-only code, that uploads a set of files, to isolate the problem. Se [mcve].